# How do I fix a noisy input device (Internal Mic)? snd_hda_intel - debug included

Tags: 12.04, sound, alsa, debug, hda-intel

As the title says, I'm having trouble with a very noisy audio input device - the internal mic or any plugged in mics.

So far I've narrowed it down to an problem in ALSA since my debug info is showing a lot of "null" values. Can anyone help?

Debug Info: http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=e0c6fb7e10624bf7691aa2b405cf0d3968e56c63

Exert from the debug:

```
model : (null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a real answer, but some debug help. I would disable pulseaudio while testing (put autospawn to /etc/pulse/client.conf and `pulseaudio -k`). Then make test recording using

```
arecord -f dat -r 44100 -D hw:0,0 test.wav
```

Play back with `aplay`. Then play around with the sample rate (-r) and with module options in /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf (reload using `sudo /sbin/alsa force-reload`). The options are position_fix, model and enable_msi. I for example got lucky by setting the model to dell (which I don't think I got), position_fix to 2 and enable_msi to 1. No real science behind this.